# Xamarin Android Screen with Stacked Tables of Data

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to fit several tables of data on a screen. For small screens, I though the best way to handle this, as a simple solution, was to have them all stacked up on top of one another. And then just to scroll down an view each table as you go down.

The tables of data need to be created with some kind of repeating, data-bound control. It seems like the ListView is the one to use with Android (but I'm open to suggestions).

The thing I am bumping up against is that you can't seem to have ListViews inside a ScrollView (note: I want to support KitKat). The rationale being that you can't have a scrollable control inside a scrollable control.

Is there any simple way of doing this? At this stage, I was hoping there'd be a simpler solution than going for the ViewPager *swipe right* option.

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to take a look at ExpandableListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ExpandableListView solved my ux dilemma here. Or rather, the MvxExpandableListView.